# Simple stack program not accepting input and crashing

Tags: c, stack

I am learning stacks right now and I decided to try to make a little program involving the stack from Magic the Gathering rules, which also follows a LIFO order.

The user asked whether they would like to

1. play a spell (push)
2. resolve a spell (pop) or
3. exit.

Now the tricky part is that I am trying to allow the elements of the stack to be multiple words each. This has been causing A LOT of problems.

I can input a word and print it outside the `while(1)` loop but if I put it inside everything goes haywire. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 100

typedef struct {
  char item[SIZE];
  int top;
} stack;

void init(stack*);
void push(stack*, char[]);
char pop(stack*);

void init(stack* st) { 
  st->top = -1; 
}

void push(stack* st, char* value) {
  if (st->top == SIZE - 1) {
    printf("STACK OVERFLOW\n");
    return;
  }
  st->top++;
  strcpy(st->item[st->top], value);
}

char pop(stack* st) {
  if (st->top == -1) {
    printf("STACK UNDERFLOW\n");
    return -1;
  }
  char value;
  strcpy(value, st->item[st->top]);
  st->top--;
  return value;
}

int main() {
  stack st1, st2;
  int choice;
  char val[20];
  init(&st1);
  init(&st2);

  printf("You have priority. What would you like to do?\n\n");
  printf("1. Cast a spell\n2. Resolve the next spell\n3. Pass priority\n\n");

  while (1) {
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch (choice) {
      case 1:
        printf("What is the spell?\n\n");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", val);
        printf("%s", val);
        push(&st1, val);
      case 2:
        strcpy(val, pop(&st1));
        printf("%s resolves.\n\n", val);
      case 3:
        exit(0);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have used the wrong tag - that is not c# code

Comment: You may want to move the first two `printf`s which serve as the menu inside the while loop. Also, `pop` is returning a single `char` not a string.

Comment: Well, you should enable compiler warning, it will instruct you about some issues: you mixed `char` and `char*` in `pop` function for instance. Actually, you stack is only able to store 20 characters, but it seems you want to store words in it... You should ask yourself: how many words (spells) do I need to store in the stack, AND what is the maximum size of a spell?

Comment: "everything goes haywire" is not very informative. And "any ideas?" is not a particularly helpful question. Do you have *any idea* what's happening in the code you wrote? If you do, then describe the problem in words. If you don't, then spend some time investigating what your code is doing so that you have a specific question. Expecting us to look at your code and figure out why it's not doing what you want when you haven't told us what you want to do is ... not reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you would be getting errors is that because of the type conversions.

```
char pop(stack* st) {
  if (st->top == -1) {
    printf("STACK UNDERFLOW\n");
    return -1;
  }
  char value;
  strcpy(value, st->item[st->top]);
  st->top--;
  return value;
}
```

The first thing, you don't need to pass the address when dealing with the arrays. The another thing is that you are trying to copy a whole string into a single character variable. So, there are so much type conversion problems in your code.

I suggest you to make the functions of void data type and provide the functionality within the block of the function. Just call the pop function with top value as an argument, and print the string within the function that you are popping. 
Stack is a zero order data structure so it doesn't require inputs for popping purpose.